# Conversão de dados em tipos como int e double

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, tipagem, conversão-de-tipo

Estou com dificuldades para fazer conversões de dados vindos de um banco de dados, por exemplo realizo uma consulta ao banco como essa:

```
carteira ca = bc.carteira.FirstOrDefault(obj => obj.cpf == cepf && obj.codigo == cod);
```

Recebo informações de dados do tipo  `ca.valor`, `ca.inicio`, ...
Gostaria de saber como converter este valor para um tipo como int, double,...
Para poder realizar as seguintes adições:

```
int result;
double soma;
int x = ca.valor + result;  
double y = ca.inicio + soma;
```

E assim poder utilizá-los em um método do meu projeto

```
chama.meuMetodo(x,y); // x e y seriam int e double
```

Confesso que esqueci como fazer esta conversão e o *seu* Google não está ajudando.

Comment: Você pode postar pra gente o *Model* do objeto `carteira`?

Comment: oi consegui resolver. Utilizei a classe Convert para fazer as conversões.  por exemplo:                              int quant = Convert.ToInt32(ca.qtdacao);

Comment: A resposta abaixo está correta? Se estiver, poderia marcá-la como aceita, em benefício da comunidade?

Comment: @user9090 qual é o tipo de ca.qtdacao?

Comment: @user9090, o correto seria você publicar sua solução como *Resposta* e marcá-la como correta, se foi o que você usou pra resolver o problema. Confira [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/201)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Experimenta isso

Java

```
Double.parseDouble(x)
Integer.parseInt(x)
```

C#

```
Convert.ToDouble(x) 
Convert.ToInt32(x)
```

Comment: oi consegui resolver. Utilizei a classe Convert para fazer as conversões.  por exemplo:                              int quant = Convert.ToInt32(ca.qtdacao);   O que estava acontecendo era que estava tentando converter o  ca e não os itens do objeto, estava tentando:                      int x = Convert.TInt(ca);  desse jeito não tinha como.